# How to start unsecured Play Server in Production mode

Tags: cookies, playframework, production

I'm developing a web server using Play Framework v2.5.
It will run in intranet and will use HTTP, not HTTPS.

When I start Play Server in Development Mode, it works.

But in Production Mode Play Server sets [`Secure`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Secure_cookie) flag to Session Cookie.

Since connection uses HTTP and not HTTPS browser doesn't send Session Cookie and users cannot login.

How can I disable this feature and avoid setting `Secure` to Cookies in Play Production Mode?

Comment: Continuing investigation: Here you can find default settings for play configuration: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/templates/play-common/conf/application.conf

Comment: If you use play2-auth then you should implement `override lazy val tokenAccessor` in your `AuthConfigImpl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set `play.http.session.secure=false` in your `application.conf` file, or in the command line:

```
$ yourapp/bin/yourapp -Dplay.http.session.secure=false
```